# Select count based on different GROUP BY in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume having 2 tables:

```
clients
id name
1  client1
2  client2
3  client3
4  client4

services
client_id service_name
1 service1
2 service2
3 service1
4 service3
1 service1
2 service3
1 service1
1 service4
1 service1
```

I need to select all clients who used any service more than 3 times. 
So I wrote a query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(s.service_name) as scount
FROM clients c
         JOIN services s ON s.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY s.client_id, s.service_name
HAVING COUNT(s.client_id) > 3
```

So the question is how to select total services count of each client alongside current extracted columns by modifying this query?

Some explanation. As we can see from service table, client1 used service1 4 times. This is what my query extracts now. But as we can see from table, client1 used different services 5 times as total. So I need to change current query to also display total count of used services for client, who used one service more than 3 times.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not as images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @herry23432: The query you wrote actually gives you the total services count of each client only, but who had more than 3 ! what else you need ,make it clear!

Comment: I added sample data and tried to explain my task. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Your second table has no PRIMARY KEY. As such, and in the context of an RDBMS, it's not really a table.

Comment: And what does it mean?

Comment: It means you should consider adding a surrogate PRIMARY KEY to your services table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother about clientid, since you only need name of client availing more then 3 services so just go with repetition of client id in service table.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(s.service_name) as scount
FROM clients c
         JOIN services s ON s.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.name, c.id
HAVING COUNT(s.service_name) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 subqueries to join to the table, each one will return the 2 counters:

```
select
  c.id, c.name,
  s.scount, t.tcount
from clients c 
inner join (
  select client_id, count(*) scount
  from services 
  group by client_id, service_name
  having count(*) > 3
) s on s.client_id = c.id 
inner join (
  select client_id, count(*) tcount
  from services 
  group by client_id
) t on t.client_id = c.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r9DZUmboiiNw9WHJZgwMJD/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name    | scount | tcount |
| --- | ------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | client1 | 4      | 5      |
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is two levels of aggregation with a window function:

```
select id, name, count(*) as num_different_services, sum(scount) as total
from (select c.id, c.name, s.service_name, count(*) as scount,
             max(count(*)) over (partition by c.id) as max_scount
      from clients c join
           services s 
           s.client_id = c.id
      group by c.id, c.name, s.service_name
     ) sc
where max_scount > 3
group by id, name;
```

Comment: mysql 5.7 do not support window functions

Comment: @herry23432 . . . But MySQL *does* and the question doesn't specify a version.